# Selenium grid IE 11 test suite issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-grid

I have a test suite that I need to run daily. Both of these suites run in grid environment with 5 nodes. When I run tests in CHROME browser everything is ok. But when I run the suite in IE 11, I am facing issues.
When I start the suite tests run on all 5 nodes. As the time passes only one node is running the tests and the test suite hangs. When I open the nodes I see no IE browser is open in other nodes and the one node where the browser is open, it is in loading state for homepage url.

Can you help me where to look for the issue.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest selenium libraries you have to use windows edge drivers in order to IE

So please check your selenium version ans select the suitable IE driver. All driver are not working for all selenium versions

Answer (score 0):

When you start the **`Selenium Grid Hub`** and **`Selenium Grid Node`** in default mode, on accessing the **`Selenium Grid Hub`** console at **`http://localhost:4444/grid/console`** you will find :

[image: BrowserStack]

Which means at maximum **`5 Chrome`**, **`5 Firefox`** and only **`1 Internet Explorer`** sessions can be initiated at a time on each node.

If you browse to the **`Configuration`** tab.

[image: GridNodeCapabilities]

Here you will find the following **`Capabilities`** those are adopted by default:

```
capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, maxInstances: 5, platform: WIN8, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}
capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, maxInstances: 5, platform: WIN8, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}
capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, maxInstances: 1, platform: WIN8, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}
```

> If you want to configure **`Selenium Grid Hub`** and **`Selenium Grid Node`** in a customized way, you have to set up the JSON configuration file and pass it as an argument while starting the **`Selenium Grid Hub`** and **`Selenium Grid Node`**